# How to configure access by host-name using web.config

Tags: c#, web-config

I am binding web app with 2 host names, example:

1. abc.com
2. xyz.com

I have a page t1.html. I would like to set permission access on file

- abc.com/t1.html  → allow
- xyz.com/t1.html → not allow to access

I guess we can do it in web.config not in code.
I did some research but most of the posts are related to authorization which doesn't help me. For example:

```
<location path="your_directory">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the rewrite module, one of the possible actions is abort, or you could redirect traffic to a different url based on the hostname.